# Should not there be "anything" instead of "nothing" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read this in "Word by Word" by Kory Samper:

> You toil onward with steady plodding, losing yourself to everything but the goal of capturing and documenting this language. Up is down, bad is good and the smallest words will be your downfall. **You'd rather do nothing else.**

What is the last highlighted part supposed to mean? Is there any pun intended? And shouldn't there be "anything" instead of "nothing" which would imply that you are so tired of the work that you'd anything except that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a cross-post of the identical question at [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/216994/shouldnt-there-be-anything-instead-of-nothing-in-this-sentence) that was posted just hours ago.

Comment: I think it's ambiguous.  "You'd rather do nothing else"  in other contexts could mean that your preference would be to do nothing beyond what you're already done, but here, it means that there is nothing else that you'd rather do -- that is, doing what you are doing now, is your favorite activity of all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's correct as it is.

In the quoted passage it says you are "losing yourself to everything but the goal of capturing and documenting this language". In other words, you're focused on this one thing. You're focused so much that "You'd rather do nothing else".

If you said "You'd rather do anything else", you're saying that you want to do anything but the task of capturing and documenting this language.

Comment: I pretty much agree with you but looking at the immediate premise, I don't think it conforms to that

Comment: @kelvin. You are totally immersed in the task "losing yourself" to everything else, so the answer above does seem to conform pretty well to the immediate premise.